# Custom Validation with React Final Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form

I am trying to add some custom validations of allowing only number(amout) in the input boxes. As per the example given on [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/10rzowm323), I tried to add custom validation.

```
const onlyAmount = value => {
  if (!value) return value
  let onlyNums = value.replace(/^\$?([0-9]{1,3},([0-9]{3},)*[0-9]{3}|[0-9]+)(.[0-9][0-9])?$/, '')
  return onlyNums
}
```

and field of my final form is like

```
<Field
  name="price"
  component="input"
  type="text"
  parse={onlyAmount}
/>
```

No the problem, its not allowing me to add numbers properly. I read the docs of the but couldn't find any helping solution.

React Final Form : https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form

Any suggestions will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Add just type="number". The keyboard will not allow other than numbers.

Comment: I know about the input type "number", but I also need to prevent using the code also.

Comment: On "onChange" function check the value is number or not. If it's number then save that in state or props

Answer (score 0):

`type="hidden"` seems like a mistake. Won't that result in a `<input type="hidden"/>`?

I have not mentally parsed your regex, but I'd recommend you try testing your parse function in that sandbox that you linked to and see why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

It's your regex. If you add a console to print out your value, then your onlyNum, you get empty string.